# SWT TableViewer - Adjust row height when horizontal scrollbar appears

Tags: java, swt

I have a TableViewer that can update the height to display x number of rows:

```
int height = tableViewer.getTable().getItemHeight() * numRowsToDisplay +
             hBar.getSize().y + H_SCROLL_PADDING;
gridData.heightHint = height;
```

I notice a special case when I have one row of data.  When the TableViewer is first loaded and displayed on the screen there is no horizontal scrollbar showing and I can see the row of data perfectly.

I then add a large value to a column which causes the column width to grow and the horizontal scrollbar appears.  This is expected behavior.  However, the horizontal scrollbar that appears covers about half of the row instead of showing up directly below the row (and adds a vertical scrollbar).  Is there a way to "push" the horizontal scrollbar down so that it doesn't cover the row (and the vertical scrollbar doesn't show)? I tried using similar code to what is shown above, but with no success. Do I have to do anything with the parent composite to allow the tableViewer to grow like this?

Comment: The only way to 'push' the horizontal bar down is to enlarge the height of the Table by the scroll-bar height. For exmple

    `height += table.getHorizontalBar().getSize().y;`

Comment: I tried that as well (that's what hBar is in the code above) but it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the `hBar`. Then it is likely that `H_SCROLL_PADDING` isn't enough. Did you try to add the actual _trim_ instead? Something like `height += table.computeTrim( 0, 0, 0, height ).height`